# Android Studio XML

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to build on-line chat system using Android studio. I am trying to implement from this tutorial:  http://www.marothiatechs.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat.html?showComment=1466367841971#c3642880730950448958

I use this code:

```
<pre> <code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/send_selected" />
<item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/send_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/send_selected" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/send" />
</selector>
<pre> </code>
```

However, I get the error message:

> X Rendering problems
>   The following classes could not be found
>       -item (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
>       -selector (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
>   Tip try to build the project.

Comment: Why do you have tags `<pre>` and  `<code>`?

Comment: Note that your closing `<pre>` isn't closed, and is out of order with the closing `</code>`.  The last line should read: `</code> </pre>`, instead.

Comment: ignore the <pre> <code> and <pre> </code> tags. I do not have them in my xml source code. They are for stackoverflow to show the text as code.

Answer (score 0):

That error will only be shown on the XML preview, your project should compile just fine.

Try changing the API level from 5.1.1 to 5.0.1.it is on upper right side corner in design of xml.

Comment: The project does not compile. I have changed the API level from 19 to 24 one by one and it does not compile